# sharepoint List Element Removal jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, sharepoint, spservices

I'm using the following code to test removing an element from a Shaerpoint list using jQuery

```
$('#RequestList').on('click', '.removeFirst', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        listName: 'ScheduleRequests',
        batchCmd: "Delete",
        ID: 0,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            alert("Item ID 0 has been removed");
        }
    });
});
```

completefunc is being run as if the removal succeeded, however the list element isn't actually being removed from the list. I believe this error is syntax related, I'm new to SPServices so I'm not certain on the syntax. Any Ideas on how to make the function remove the first list element?

Comment: Are you sure that there is an item with ID 0?

Comment: Yes I'm fairly certain, I'm using another part of code to generate div IDs based on the index of the list items, and I'm getting 0-4 for the indexes (5 test cases)

Comment: I never see a SharePoint list item with ID 0 before...have you tried to delete an other ID? And maybe you should add the `async: true` option...

Comment: List Item IDs are autogenerated sequence numbers and starts with 1 and what method are you using to generate div IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID is the ID automatically generated by Sharepoint. It starts at 1. For each item created into a list you have this unique ID. It's this one you need to use.

You may also want to check my API library I did to deal with Sharepoint. I think it's more intuitive than SPServices... : http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.list.html#.remove